# Remove duplicates in particular column sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, duplicates

Hi i have records for a column in  below format in sql server 2008 table

```
code1--codename1;code2--codename2;code3--codename3;code4--codename4;code2--codename2;code5--codename5;code1--codename1;code3--codename3;code6--codename6;code2--codename2;code7--codename7;


code1--codename1;code2--codename2;code3--codename3;code4--codename4;code2--codename2;code5--codename5;code1--codename1;code3--codename3;code6--codename6;code2--codename2;code7--codename7;
```

is there any way to remove the duplicates in this column like we have code1--codename1 duplicated . all the values are separated by semicolon in a particular column

Regards
Prasad

Comment: Why do you store multiple values in one column at all? Have you ever heard of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)?

Answer (score 0):

delete any column manually and start using a primary key i.e.: ID else this may be possible